# Почему цикл перебора страниц не закакнчивается?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

Я пишу скраппер на pupeet puppeteer и cherio. Он должен зайти на сайт и ввест и делать поиск по ключевикам по очереди, собрать данные, если есть следуйщая страница то перейти и сделать там тоже самое. Когда конпки далее нет, все в порядке,но когда она появляеется он начинает увеличевать счетчик страниц и цикл происходит бессконечно. Я не понимаю почему

```
  let pageNumber = process.env.PUP_STARTPAGE;
  let lastPage = false;
  //projects?name=верстка%20сайтов&page=3
  const keyWords = await knex.select('*').from('account').leftJoin('word', 'account.id', 'word.account_id')
  for (let word of keyWords) {
    lastPage = false
    while (!lastPage) {
      const URL = `${process.env.PUP_URL}name=${word.value.replace(/\s/ig, '%20')}&page=${pageNumber}`;
      const content = await loadPageContent({options: ['--no-sandbox', 
                                            '--disable-setuid-sandbox', 
                                            '--start-maximized'],
                                            headless: false,
                                            defaultViewport: Number(process.env.PUP_DEFAULTVIEWPORT)}, 
                                            word.cookies, URL )
        const $ = cheerio.load(content) 
        const projectsItems = [];
  
        const nextButton = $('body > div.main-content > div.container.page-container > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.col-md-9.col-md-push-3 > div.pagination > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a')
        if (!nextButton.length > 0) lastPage = true; 
        $('a.visitable').each((i, header) => {
        const url = $(header).attr('href')
        const title = $(header).text()
    
        projectsItems.push({
            title,
            url,
        })
  })
  
  //await listItemsHandler(projectsItems)
  pageNumber++
  }
  pageNumber = process.env.PUP_STARTPAGE
  
}
}
```

Comment: Видимо `if (!nextButton.length > 0)`  не срабатывает...... не проще ли взять отладчик и посмотреть в нём? Просто не ясно, что вы ожидаете что тут ответят?

Comment: if (nextButton.length <= 0) lastPage = true; <-- тут вроде как